# vue-cli build not using minified versions of libraries

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am trying to reduce the size of my SPA build, which gets build using `vue-cli build`. I am using Chart.js and after building the application, I ran `webpack-bundle-analyzer` and it shows Chart.js with it's full size, and not `chart.min.js`.

[image]

What I am expecting is that it would use `/dist/chart.min.js`. I am not understanding this correctly, or is it actually using the non-minified file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around to having another look at this and this is simply because `vue-chartjs` needs `chart.js` as peer dependency and is thus not taking care of anything in **my side** of the build step.

Related: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/249

The fix is to configure it accordingly in the webpack config:

```
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'chart.js$': 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js',
            },
        },
```